# Is it correct to say "your waistband is folded inward, adjust it" or "your waistband is twisted..." or "your waistband is tucked in..."?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

Sometimes, a child puts on their shorts or pants carelessly and the waistband might get folded inwards as shown in the above picture.

People won't see the waistband and it also makes the child uncomfortable too.

**Is it correct to say?:**

-*Your waistband is folded inward, adjust it!*

-*your waistband is twisted, turn it out!*

-*your waistband is tucked in, untuck it!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The twisting of the waistband put it in the wrong position. Similarly the turning of it put it in the wrong position. So did the tucking. The twisting, turning and tucking are now finished, whereas the waistband is still in the wrong position.

I therefore see no reason to choose one over any other.

Comment: some native speakers suggest to say "it is folded inward, turn it out"

Comment: Folded could be included in the list, as could reversed, rolled and others. It makes no significant difference. It may be put into the correct position by using the verbs in the opposite direction.

Comment: I suggest that most native speakers would say “I suggest saying ....” rather than “I suggest to say ...”